# Are there functions s.t. $f+\varepsilon g$ is in the same function space but not $f$ and $g$?

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces

Is there an example where $f$ is some function in some function space $\Omega_1$ and $g$ is some function in another function space $\Omega_2$ such that $g\not\in \Omega_1$ but for some $\varepsilon\in (0,d]$ we have $f+\varepsilon g\in \Omega_1$?

If yes, I wonder if there is a useful example where $g$ does not depend on $\varepsilon$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f,f+\varepsilon g \in \Omega_1$ we have that also $\varepsilon g=(f+\varepsilon g)-f  \in \Omega_1$ and hence $g \in \Omega_1$.

(in case we are taking about real vector spaces)

Comment: I see, so it is impossible. Thank you very much!

Comment: Why should $\Omega_1$ be stable under addition?

Comment: @Jujustum Vector spaces tend to have this property.

Comment: seems legit lol, sorry